# How do I write usage of a command unix

Tags: unix, command

I have to write a command that rules with certain arguments.I need to show a message of usage of this command.I tried this:

```
if [ $1 = 'help' ]; then
echo Usage: '-a arguments at-author....'
fi
```

It doesn't work.Why?

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't work"? What error message do you get?

Comment: How are you calling your script? Apparently, "help" is not the first argument.

Comment: The thing is I do this for a homework that check my script.I have more arguments for the script but I need to see the usage when I call it with 'help'

Comment: @user3022764 still not clear at all what exactly you're doing and what exactly "doesn't work".

Answer (score 0):

```
case "$1" in
"help" ) 
    echo "Usage ...." ;;
*)  echo "others..." ;;
esac
```